# How to make it so that the word "male" is not counted as in "female"?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
gender = input("What is your gender? ")
if 'male' in gender:
    print("You are a boy!")
if 'female' in gender:
    print("You are a girl!")
```

May I ask how do I make it so that "***male***" won't be counted part of "***female***"?

It would always print "**You are a boy**!"

Comment: How about take an exact match like `'gender' == 'male'`?

Comment: @Cat Accept and upvote answers if you feel it would be helpful for future users. For this use the tick and up arrow near left top of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

To obtain the result as you mentioned edit your code as follows :

```
gender = input("What is your gender? ")
if 'male' == gender:
    print("You are a boy!")
if 'female' == gender:
    print("You are a girl!")
```

Answer (score 4):

First, check for the 'female' condition.

Then use an elif statement to check for the 'male' condition.

If the first statement comes out true then the second statement will not be checked.

```
gender = input("What is your gender? ")
if 'female' in gender:
    print("You are a girl!")
elif 'male' in gender:
    print("You are a boy!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Many possibilites:

```
gender = input("What is your gender? ")

if 'female' in gender:
    print("You are a girl!")
else:
    print("You are a boy!")
```

or

```
enter code here

if gender == 'male':
    print("You are a boy!")
if gender == 'female':
    print("You are a girl!")
```

or

```
if gender == 'male':
    print("You are a boy!")
elif gender == 'female':
    print("You are a girl!")
else:
   print("You seem to be a magical dragon")
```

Possibly a good idea to sanitize the inout to lower string

```
gender.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
gender = input("What is your gender? ")
if re.findall(r'\bmale\b', gender):
    print("You are a boy!")
elif re.findall(r'\bfemale\b', gender):
    print("You are a girl!")
```

[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

example output:

```
What is your gender? >? i am male
You are a boy!
What is your gender? >? i am female
You are a girl!
What is your gender? >? male
You are a boy!
What is your gender? >? female
You are a girl!
What is your gender? >? maleAndFemale
What is your gender?
```